# Why sftp login does not land in chroot directory from linux to windows?

Tags: linux, windows, sftp

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel DEBUG

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

ForceCommand internal-sftp

Match User TestUser
    ChrootDirectory "E:\DataFileIntegrator\Data"

#Match Group administrators
#       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

Instead of landing in the chrootdirectory `"E:\DataFileIntegrator\Data"` why does it lands in `/C:/Users/TestUser`

```
[mylinux_prompt$ sftp Testuser@myhostname.com
Connected to myhostname.com.
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /C:/Users/TestUser
```

**Open ssh version installed on windows is 8.6.0.0.p1-Beta**

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Windows OpenSSH repository](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/140), the `ChrootDirectory` functionality doesn't work on Windows:

> Chroot feature does not work in Windows. In Windows sftp server, home directories are set to the user's actual home directories ( like c:/users/username or c:/users/suername.domainname )

This should not be especially surprising, since as far as I'm aware, Windows doesn't implement the `chroot` system call and therefore couldn't possibly implement this feature correctly.

Comment: it works according to the link for the latest version but i was unable to make it work per user basis https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/190#:~:text=v7.7.0.0%2C%20it%20works-,Match%20User%20test,-ChrootDirectory%20c%3A%5Ctemp